# Как найти русскоязычные Git команды?

Tags: git, team

В Git множество англоязычных проектов. Попадаются и такие, где все общаются на китайском. Или испанском.
А существуют ли русскоязычные команды и проекты Git? Как их найти? Если я захочу сделать свой проект Git чтобы разработчики общались по-русски, то как зазвать интересующихся?

Comment: Git — это система контроля версий. Это не сайт, это не проект, это не соцсеть, это не сообщество. Поэтому вопрос не имеет смысла

Comment: вы случаем git и github.com не смешиваете?

Comment: @andreymal Когда Вы не поняли смысла вопроса, это не всегда значит, что смысла нет.

Comment: @user7860670 Отнюдь не смешиваю. Говорил вовсе не только о сайте GitHub, а о любых Git проектах. Забавно, кто и почему пометил неадекватный вопросу ответ Андрея Крачевского как ответ.

Comment: @Плавающий характеризовать проекты по используемой системе контроля версий — максимально бессмысленно. Чем вам не угодили «Mercurial-проекты» или «SVN-проекты»? А что если проект не использует никакую систему версий? В чём причина выделять именно «Git-проекты»?

Comment: Тот ответ не помечен, как ответ, только +2 голоса. А что касается любого git проекта, то его следует вести на английском, даже в русскоязычной команде, используя строго портабильные имена для файлов.

Comment: @andreymal Вам ли судить о смысле и бессмысленности, когда Вы ведете разговор о Git-проектах, а в вопросе речь - о Git-командах. Просто Вы тоже ответа на вопрос не знаете, зато с избытком имеете в чем упрекнуть.

Comment: @user7860670 При чем здесь имена файлов проектов? Речь шла не о проектах, а о командах. Не видели испаноязычные или китайские команды? Просто напросто участников русскоязычных команд или знающих о таких тут не нашлось.

Comment: @Плавающий характеризовать команды по используемей системе контроля версий столь же максимально бессмысленно, намного более бессмысленно чем по языку общения. Нормальная команда должна делом заниматься, а не на Git молиться. Многие команды меняют системы контроля версий туда-сюда по потребностям, и ничего, нормально живут.

Comment: Если речь о командах разработчиков, то при чем тут git? Вопрос у вас как-то совсем не по теме. Идите на hh или какой-нибудь фриланс (они еще остались?) сайт и зазывайте там разработчиков, умеющих пользоваться git.

Answer (score 4):

*GIT* - **система контроля версий**. Похоже, вы имеете в виду *GitHub* -- крупнейший **хостинг** для размещения на нём своих проектов. **Вы явно путаете терминологию**.

GitHub используется по всему миру -> разработчики хостят свои проекты на своём языке (что логично). UPD: на самом деле, принято использовать **только английский**, чтобы разработчики со всего мира смогли работать над проектом.

Отвечаю на ваш вопрос: пользуйтесь GitHub-ом, учите английский, 99% проектов на нём. Русских проектов навалом, но все они ведутся на английском, потому что, ИМХО, так принято в IT комьюнити. Никто не будет приходить к вам на проект, только потому что он на русском -- это полнейший бред, развивать нужно **идею**.

Мне вообще не понятно, почему вы так хотите ограничиться от мирового сообщества, оставляя несоизмеримо маленькое -- СНГ-шное. Так нельзя делать!

P.S. По вашей формулировке вопроса понятно, что вы не понимаете пока, зачем всё это надо.Я постарался **максимально кратко** рассказать про эту "штуку". Поэтому, изучите вопрос, почитайте WIKI, тогда станет понятнее.

Comment: спасибо. Я имел в виду именно Git-команды, не важно хостятся ли их проекты на GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket или где-то еще. Похоже, что Вы хотели сказать "я русскоязычных команд и средств их поиска не знаю" но предпочли считать что не знаю чего-то я.